# i18next-scanner using keys with variables

Tags: i18next

I have a list x = ['a', 'b', 'c'] and load translations using t(`vars.${x[i]}`).

When I used i18next-scanner, I get a records under vars with key "".

I have already defined in comments, e.g., // t('vars.a'); , so this is picked up by the scanner. How can I eliminate so that i18next-scanner does not also add an empty key?